# Unable to get value of variable in laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

Laravel 6. PHP 7.4

I've a form where I can upload multiple images. My images are uploading into storage folder and now I'm interested to find a way to get the path of all uploaded images so that I can save into databases.

I just started with a simple method of getting path and good news is I got the path but the variable containing the path is not accessible outside If clause on hitting code:

```
  $store_seller->save();
```

I am trying to figure out how I can upload the multiple strings as paths of images.

Blade

```
 <form method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data" id="msform" 
     action="{{route('niceActionController.multiStepStore')}}">

      <div id="dropzoneForm" required class="dropzone"></div>

</form>
```

Controller

```
public function multiStepStore(Request $request)
{
$store_seller = new Sellers();
    
    $store_seller->generation = $request['generation'];
    $store_seller->trim = $request['trim'];
    $store_seller->regist_year = $request['regist_year'];
    $store_seller->emission_class = $request['emission_class'];
    $store_seller->engine_type = $request['engine_type'];
    $store_seller->gearbox = $request['gearbox'];
    $store_seller->engine_volume = $request['engine_volume'];
    $store_seller->engine_power = $request['engine_power'];

    $now = date('Y-m-d');
    $request['maintenance'] = $now;
    $store_seller->maintenance =$request['maintenance'];
    $store_seller->maintenance = $now;


      if ($request->file('file')!=null)
      {

        $filename = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
        $image = $request->file('file')->storeAs('public/images',$filename);
        $store_seller->img_path = $image;

      }

      $store_seller->save();

}
```

`dd($store_seller);` returns all the values into database except the **img_path**.

Comment: try debug your $image, `dd($image);`

Comment: You should try with `$request->hasFile('file')` to check file condition.

Comment: And you should check your model file. You have to include `img_path` field in fillable array.

Comment: @SiddharajsinhZala
My fillable array has "img_path" and $request->hasFile('file') doesn't work in my scenario. I explained it below in my comment.

Comment: Can you try to assign static or some random string to img_path and try?

Comment: @SiddharajsinhZala  If I shifted all of my code into If clause, img_path are saved into database but the other values not. Don't know why

Answer (score 0):

It can be because the request doent contain the `file` field like you expect.
so the `if` conditions body is never executed.

try to see if the request has it.

```
if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
    return $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
} else {
    dd('no file!')
}
```

And I see from the html template you are using dropzone, In dropzone the file uploads can be triggered irrespective of the form. so check its documentation and make sure you are using it correctly. And make sure your file input field is having a name (in your case you have used `file` only).

Comment: Your code returns 'no file' and it returns no image into strorage. 

I already had checked with condition hasFile(). My condition is working fine otherwise It shouldn't return uploaded images into storage folder but it does. Only the issue is how would I get the variable $image outside the If clause. 
If it's accessible outside the If clause, path will be saved.

Comment: Another interested thing, If I shifted all of mu code into If clause, img_path will be saved into database but other values not. Don't know why..